# Actionbar showing a background even when there is none

Tags: android, background-image, android-actionbar-compat

I am using a custom theme to show custom background on my actionbar. M using Actionbar Compat. I run on different devices and it gave strange result in mobiles + versions < 3.0. So after some testing i found out that even after i set a transparent color as my background m still getting something. same code works fine on my nexus 4. See the attached picture.

[image]

**My Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.abtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**My Styles:**

```
<style name="Widget.Custom.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.Common" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Custom.Common">
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
</style>
```

**My Actionbar Background:**

```
<color name="actionbar_background">#00000000</color>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `android:windowContentOverlay` into your `CustomActionBarTheme` definition. E.g.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, congrats for having a "ur" nexus 4.
Try add this too in MyActionBar

```
<item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
```

Comment: Since it's already working in 3.0+, this will have no effect.

Comment: lol, Don't envy, God will give you one too.. :PP and it doesn't have any effect. i mean, no change.